# Is it safe to remove Per user queued Windows Error Reporting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-cleanup

I was cleaning up my laptop hard-disk, running Windows 7, and as part of the process I ran the Disk Cleanup utility. To my surprise I saw 2 items in the list that were quite large (both ~300MB).

- Per user queued Windows Error Reporting
- System queued Windows Error Reporting

I guess I had never noticed these, because they were never that big. So, what are these items? Any particular reason why they became so large all of a sudden? And finally, is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just part of the error reporting system that reports application errors and the technical information surrounding them to Microsoft (the main user interface for this is the dialogs which appear when programs crash saying that "X encountered a problem and needs to close"). 'Queued' just means that it contains error reports that haven't been sent yet for whatever reason, and as such have been stored locally on your hard disk, waiting to be sent. They are both safe to remove.

Comment: Is there any way to force the queue to be processed?

Comment: @Deebster: see comments on this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/21784/137255